# Suppose $\sum |A_n|^2 <\infty$, then $\sum r^{|n|} A_n e^{inx}$ converges uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Suppose $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |A_n|^2$ converges. Show that for each $r\in (0,1)$, the series $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|} A_n e^{inx}$ converges uniformly in $x$.

I know that the series $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|} e^{inx}$ converges uniformly in $x$ by M-test. If we can find $M>0$ such that $|A_n| < M$ for all $n$, then we are done. But I am not sure how to get that? Since $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |A_n|^2$ converges, then $|A_n|^2$ is bounded. Is that it?

Comment: if $a_n$ does not $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $\sum_n a_n$ cannot converge, yes

Comment: and no, $|A_n| < M$ doesn't prove that $f(r) = \sum_n r^{|n|} A_n e^{inx}$ converges uniformly on $r \in (0,1)$, but only on $r \in [0,1-\epsilon]$ for every fixed $\epsilon < 0$  (try with $A_n = 1$ if $n \ge 0$ , $A_n = 0$ otherwise, $f_N(r) = \sum_{n=0}^N r^n e^{inx} = \frac{1}{1-r e^{ix}}$ )

Comment: Do you: have an inner product on your space of Fourier series? know Parseval's theorem? know a set of functions dense in the space of your sums with summands containing $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}nx}$? have experience with the spaces $\ell^2$ or $L^2(\Bbb{T})$?  Any of those would help.

Comment: By Cauchy-Schwarz, $\sum_n |r^{|n|}A_ne^{inx}|=\sum_n |r^{|n|}||A_n| \le \left( \sum_{n}r^{2|n|}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n}|A_n|^2\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, I know Fourier series and Parseval's theorem.

Comment: @TrialAndError Oh OK that's obvious, now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.